# Get certain columns from uneven-indexed excel files in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science

I have 25 excel files that have data for each city inside Peru, but the index-column varies.

certain files are like this:

```
1      2      3            4                    46       ...   <- index number (for visualization purposues)
A     |B     |C           |D       |.... |      AT      |...   <- index column
ubigeo|código|departamento|distrito|.... |Acceso a agua |...  <- Header
value |value |value       |value   |.... |value         |...   data
value |value |value       |value   |.... |value         |...     
value |value |value       |value   |.... |value         |...     |
.      .      .            .        .     .                      v
.      .      .            .        .     .
.      .      .            .        .     .
value |value |value       |value   |.... |value         |...
```

and the rest are like:

```
1      2      3            4                    46                   48        |   <- index number (for visualization purposues)
A     |B     |C           |D       |.... |      AT      |.... |      AV        |   <- index column
ubigeo|código|departamento|distrito|.... |Cemento       |.... | Acceso al agua |   <- Header
value |value |value       |value   |.... |value         |.... |    value       |   
value |value |value       |value   |.... |value         |.... |    value       |   data
value |value |value       |value   |.... |value         |.... |    value       |    
.      .      .            .        .     .                .         .              |
.      .      .            .        .     .                .         .              v
.      .      .            .        .     .                .         .
value |value |value       |value   |.... |value         |.... |    value       |
```

For merging all those excel files i've written the following

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyr)

setwd("~/Data")

datos_censo <- list.files(pattern = "*.xls")
datos_censo

procesado = lapply(datos_censo,
                   function(i){
                     x = read_excel(i, sheet = 1, skip = 1)
                     x = x[,c(1,2,3,4,5,8,46)] # index column numbers
                     x
                   }
                   )
```

and it works for the first 6 retrieved columns but for the last column it is either "Acceso a agua" or "Cemento".

My question is
**How can I do for getting only the desired column "Acceso a agua" (which index-number is 46 for some files and 48 for others) along with the first ones(column indexes: 1,2,3,4,5,8) ?**

Comment: Would it work for you to instead use `select()`? For example, x %>% select(`ubigeo`, `código`, ..., `Acceso a agua`) ?

Comment: I guess you meant this:
.
.
.
```procesado = lapply(datos_censo,
                   function(i){
                     x = read_excel(i, sheet = 1, skip = 1)
                     x %>% select(Ubigeo, CCPP, Departamento, Provincia, Distrito)
                     x
                   }
                   )
```
And an error is yielded:
      Error in select(., Ubigeo, CCPP, Departamento, Provincia, Distrito) : 
      could not find function "select"

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified. It's from the package `dplyr`